# Can't get Altair (emulator) to run image from disk 0

Tags: emulation

I'm using the [Altair emulator](http://www.altair32.com), and in the documentation it says: "toggle the address 0xff00 into the front panel and toggle RUN" to load the image from disk.

So if you convert the hex 0xff00 into decimal you get 65280, so I selected that numbers on the emulator and clicked run, but it doesn't want to run the image linked to my disk 0.

Any oldies that can help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your altair32.ini file contain? The one that ships with the package has:

```
[fileformat]
version=3.0
[windows]
main=org=8,20, size=644,339
[ROMS]
ROM0=88dskrom,0000,0
```

but my understanding is that the disk boot ROM should go in the last 256 bytes of RAM. I can't test it since I'm not running Windows, but I would change that last line to:

```
ROM0=88dskrom,ff00,0
```

and give it another shot.